# VBA For statement with userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the userform for inputing data and used following codes to trasnfer te data to excel:

```
    Cells(1,1).Value = Textbox1.Value
    Cells(1,2).Value = Textbox2.Value
    Cells(1,3).Value = Textbox3.Value
......
    Cells(1,57).Value = Textbox57.Value
    Cells(1,58).Value = Textbox58.Value
    Cells(1,59).Value = Textbox59.Value
```

I am going to simplified with the followings

```
Dim i As integer

For i = 1 to 59
Cells(1,i).Value = "Textbox" & i.Value
Next
```

But error occurs on the "Textbox" & i.Value part

Please suggest, thank you

Comment: Try ("TextBox" & i).Value or Controls("TextBox" & i).Value

Comment: You may have to use formname.Controls or Me.Controls

Comment: It works perfect with Controls("TextBox" & i).Value, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 to 59
Cells(1,i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
Next
```